# Best way to defend against Path Traversal in php

Tags: php

I have this bit of code:

```
<?php
$file=htmlentities($_POST['configdata']);
print ("About to show this configuration file:" . $file);
echo "<p></p>";
$results = system("type $file");

print "data is " . $results;
?>
```

What do I need to implement in order to protect against path traversal? 
I have been trying to figure this out for too long. 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: check the parameter against a whitelist of allowed files.

Comment: I apologize but what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: @Stackhouse He means define a list of possible values (configuration files, in your case, apparently) and only allow paths that belong to that list.

Comment: Worth having a look here: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/159224

Answer (score 1):

One example:

```
<?php
$whitelist = [
    'Apache' => '/apache/directory/httpd/conf/httpd.conf',
    'PHP' => '/php/directory/php/php.ini',
    'MySQL' => '/mysql/directory/mysql/my.ini'
];

if (! empty($_POST['configdata']) && isset($whitelist[$_POST['configdata']])) {
    $hd = fopen($whitelist[$_POST['configdata']], 'r');
    $content = fread($hd, filesize($whitelist[$_POST['configdata']]));
    fclose($hd);
    echo $content;
    exit;
} else {
    if (! empty($_POST['configdata'])) {
        echo '<p>Invalid option, please try again</p>';
    }
    $options = '';
    foreach ($whitelist as $k => $v) {
        $options .= "<option value=\"{$k}\">{$k}</option>";
    }
    $html = <<<HTML
<form method="POST">
    <select name="configdata">
        <option>Select file</option>
        {$options}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Try" />
</form>
HTML;
  echo $html;
}
```

Comment: It is for an assignment. When I run an attack using ZAP, I get alerts for Path Traversal. I kinda understand what you're saying but still don't understand what needs to be done.

Comment: I guess my question is, how can i create a whitelist to allow specified files?

Comment: The first line `$configs=[...]` is whitelist, you also can use array there, like `$whitelist=[file1, file2...]`.  The value of `$_POST['configdata']` must match one in whitelist, else then ignore it or throw error like 'invalid file'.

Comment: Oh ok, I see what you're saying! Thanks for clearing that up Nick.

Comment: What if I only wanted to have one specific file from one directory be in the whitelist?

Comment: ha, you can say `if($_POST['configdata'] != '/your/path/and/file.name') new Exception('Invalid')`